# Assign different values ​to a string using a for

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following structure `for`

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstArquivosRetorno.Items.Count; i++)
{
    lstArquivosRetorno.SetSelected(i, true);

    string nomeArquivo = string.Format(
      "{0}{1}", 
       Funcoes.IncludeBackSlash(edtPathArquivo.Text),
       lstArquivosRetorno.SelectedItem.ToString());

    _relacaoArquivos.Add(nomeArquivo);
}
```

What I'm doing is the following: I have a `List<string> _relacaoArquivos` and I add the filename to that list using that structure, however, if I have more than one file selected, it only stores and adds the first file.

How can I go through my `for` structure to store and add the names of all files to the list?

Comment: My crystal ball says that this is a ListBox and it has its SelectionMode set to allow more than one selection.  That's why it also has a SelectedItems property.  Don't select, use Items[i].ToString() directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lstArquivosRetorno` looks like a select list or similar. When creating the `nomeArquivo` string, the `SelectedItem` is being used to create the string. That is why you're getting only one item added to the `_relacaoArquivos` list.

`lstArquivosRetorno.SelectedItem` should be `lstArquivosRetorno.Items[i]`

```cs
string nomeArquivo = string.Format(
      "{0}{1}", 
       Funcoes.IncludeBackSlash(edtPathArquivo.Text),
       lstArquivosRetorno.Items[i]); // no need to call ToString()
```